# Scala: Map keys with wildcards?

Tags: scala, dictionary, key-value

Is it possible to use keys with wildcards for Scala Maps? For example tuples of the form (x,_)? Example:

```
scala> val t1 = ("x","y")
scala> val t2 = ("y","x")
scala> val m = Map(t1 -> "foo", t2 -> "foo")

scala> m(("x","y"))
res5: String = foo

scala> m(("x",_))
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => scala.Tuple2("x", x$1))
              m(("x",_))
                     ^
```

It would be great if there was a way to retrieve all (composite_key, value) pares where only some part of composite key is defined. Other ways to get the same functionality in Scala?

Comment: Does it even make sense in this particular example? It's not a multimap, so it has only one entry per key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using comprehensions like this:

```
for ( a @ ((k1,k2), v) <- m  if k1 == "x" ) yield a
```

Answer (score 2):

How about use collect

```
Map( 1 -> "1" -> "11", 2 -> "2" -> "22").collect { case (k@(1, _), v ) => k -> v }
```

Comment: Thanks! Will `collect` traverse _all_ keys in this case? I mean how efficient will it be for a huge collection? O(n)?

Comment: Yes, `collect` traverses all tuples in the map exactly once. So you could argue it's O(n), BUT you could have: `{case (k@(1, _), v ) if pred => ...}` where pred is a boolean function with O(2^n). Then your collect would be O(n*2^n). So it depends on the collecting function.

Comment: It is not clear how predicate function will help to reduce traverse. As I understand predicate should be tested on all keys of the map, so all elements will be traveresed anyway. Could you please give a code example? Thanks!

Comment: You had to traverses keys if you use one map. Or you may need the predicate of key as another map.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can do something like

```
m.filter(m => (m._1 == "x"))
```

but in your particular example it will still return only one result, because a Map has only one entry per key. If your key itself is composite then it will indeed make more sense:

```
scala>  Map((1,2)->"a", (1,3)->"b", (3,4)->"c").filter(m => (m._1._1 == 1))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Int, Int),String] = Map((1,2) -> a, (1,3) -> b)
```

Comment: Is there any practical difference between `collect` and `filter` ?

Comment: they both do more or less the same (filtering list based on some criteria, preserving the order of the elements), but collect uses a PartialFunction which does not have to be defined on all elements of the collection (and will only run on the elements for which it is defined).

Comment: Will collect traverse all keys in the map? I mean how efficient will it be for a huge collection? O(n)?

Comment: The docs say collect runs only on the elements for which its PartialFunction is defined. But I think it's unlikely that it still does not have to traverse the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what is happening under the hood of the `Map`. The default `Map` in Scala is `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`, which stores things based on their hash codes. Do `("x", "y")` and `("x", "y2")` have hash codes that relate to each other in anyway? No, they don't, and their is no efficient way to implement wildcards with this map. The other answers provide solutions, but these will iterate over key/value pair in the entire `Map`, which is not efficient.

If you expect you are going to want to do operations like this, use a `TreeMap`. This doesn't use a hash table internally, put instead puts elements into a tree based on an ordering. This is similar to the way a relational database uses B-Trees for its indices. Your wildcard query is like using a two-column index to filter on the first column in the index.

Here is an example:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

val t1 = ("x","y")
val t2 = ("x","y2")
val t3 = ("y","x")
val m = TreeMap(t1 -> "foo1", t2 -> "foo2", t3 -> "foo3")

// "" is < than all other strings
// "x\u0000" is the next > string after "x"
val submap = m.from(("x", "")).to(("x\u0000", ""))

submap.values.foreach(println) // prints foo1, foo2
```

Comment: i added plus one because I found the reminder to think about things in terms of hash codes was actually useful !